# VBA cannot get data from HTML with .getElementsByTag() nor .getElementByID()

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

My current project consists of retrieving data from HTML source code.
Specifically, I am looking at crash cases on this website:

https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=112007272

I would like to gather all relevant data from the HTML by looking for `.innertext` of specific tags/IDs.

My code so far:

```
Sub ExtractData()

mystart:

'First I create two Internet Explorer object

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")      'this browser contains the list of cases
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 1600
objIE.Height = 900
objIE.Visible = True 'We can see IE

Set objIEdata = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")    'this browser opens the specific case
objIEdata.Top = 0
objIEdata.Left = 0
objIEdata.Width = 1600
objIEdata.Height = 900
objIEdata.Visible = True 'We can see IE

On Error Resume Next
objIE.navigate ("https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/LegacyCDS/Index")        'url of website

Do
    DoEvents
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        objIE.Quit
        Set objIE = Nothing
        GoTo mystart:
    End If
Loop Until objIE.readystate = 4

'we define an object variable Alllinks and loop through all the links to search for

Set aAlllinks = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")                'looks for Search Button 
For Each Hyperlink In aAlllinks
    If Hyperlink.innertext = " Search" Then
        Hyperlink.Click
        Exit For
    Else
        MsgBox "Search Button was not found. Please improve code!"
    End If

Next

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

Set bAlllinks = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")                     'all Hyperlinks on webpage start with Tag "a"
For Each Hyperlink In bAlllinks
    If UBound(Split(Hyperlink.innertext, "-")) = 2 And Len(Hyperlink.innertext) = 11 Then             'case specific to find the Hyperlinks which contain cases
        Debug.Print Hyperlink.innertext

        '2nd IE is used for each case

restart:
            objIEdata.navigate (Hyperlink.href)        'url of each case

            Do
                DoEvents
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    objIEdata.Quit
                    Set objIE = Nothing
                    GoTo restart:
                End If
            Loop Until objIEdata.readystate = 4

            Set register = objIEdata.document.getElementByTagName("tbody")             'objIEdata.document.getElementByID("main").getElementByID("mainSection")  '.getElementByID("bodyMain").getElementsByTagName("tbody")
            For Each untermenue In register
                Debug.Print untermenue.innerHTML
            Next

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))




    End If
Next




objIE.Quit
objIEdata.Quit

End Sub
```

Note that the visibility of IE is just for debugging reasons.

The part which confuses me is

`Set register = objIEdata.document.getElementByTagName("tbody")`.

If I look for `.TagName("tbody")` the variable register is returned empty and the same happens if I look for `.ID("bodyMain")`. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with HTML and how VBA interacts with a HTML document. I was under the impression that I could address all elements by their ID, if they happen to have one, but this does not seem to work.

Do I need to work myself through the HTML "branches" or should the code be able to find each ID, no matter the "child" it is to be found in?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly are you after? Everything on the page?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. I do not need hyperlinks to XML and stuff, but basically I need all the information in the tables. In the end I would like to have a CSV or filled excel sheet, which shows all the data for each case with the property that same categories are in the same column. I also do not need the pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is a pretty big request so I am going to give some pointers and starting code. My code should write out all the tables but you will want to play around to get your desired format. There is certainly enough logic around selecting elements efficiently that this should help. * I haven't tested the use of the class to loop over all retrieved ids due time contraints but have tested the individual case and the retrieval of all ids.

---

**To get the initial case links and ids:**

I might use a function returning an array containing the links and ids. If you extract the ids they can be passed the XMLHTTP request I show below.

URL is https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/LegacyCDS/Search

```
Public Function GetLinksAndIds(ByVal URL) As Variant
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, i As Long
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("btnSubmit1").Click

         While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim caseLinks As Object, id As String, newURL As String
        Set caseLinks = .document.querySelectorAll("[href*='CaseID=']")

        Dim linksAndIds()
        ReDim linksAndIds(1 To caseLinks.Length, 1 To 2)
        For i = 0 To caseLinks.Length - 1
           linksAndIds(i + 1, 1) = caseLinks.item(i)
           linksAndIds(i + 1, 2) = Replace$(caseLinks.item(i), "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=", vbNullString)
        Next

        .Quit
    End With
    GetLinksAndIds = linksAndIds
End Function
```

**Example return values:**

[image]

---

**For each case - using XMLHTTP:**

I would be tempted to avoid IE and use [`XMLHTTP` request](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) (url encoded query string returning more readable page version using the print option). Although I have parsed using css selectors you can read the response into an `MSXML2.DOMDocument60` and query with `XPath` for example. You can concatenate caseid into URL.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTables()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewPage&xsl=Case.xsl&tab=Crash&form=CaseForm&baseNode=&vehnum=-1&occnum=-1&pos=-1&pos2=-1&websrc=true&title=Crash%20Overview%20-%20Summary&caseid=112007272&year=&fullimage=false", False '<==concatenate caseid into URL
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = .responseText
    End With

    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = sResponse
    Dim tables As Object, i As Long
    Set tables = html.querySelectorAll("table")
    For i = 0 To tables.Length - 1
        clipboard.SetText tables.item(i).outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ws.Cells(LastRow(ws) + 2, 1).PasteSpecial
    Next
End Sub

'https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm '<< Function below modified from here

Public Function LastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

**What might it look like altogether (not tested) using a class to hold the xmlhttp object:**

**Class clsHTTP:**

```
Option Explicit

Private http As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        sResponse = .responseText
    End With
End Function
```

**Standard module 1:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTables()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim initialLinksURL As String, http As clsHTTP, i As Long, j As Long, newURL As String
    Set http = New clsHTTP
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    initialLinksURL = "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/LegacyCDS/Search"

    Dim linksAndIds()
    linksAndIds = GetLinksAndIds(initialLinksURL)

    For i = LBound(linksAndIds, 2) To UBound(linksAndIds, 2)

        newURL = "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewPage&xsl=Case.xsl&tab=Crash&form=CaseForm&baseNode=&vehnum=-1&occnum=-1&pos=-1&pos2=-1&websrc=true&title=Crash%20Overview%20-%20Summary&caseid=" & linksAndIds(i, 2) & "&year=&fullimage=false"
        html.body.innerHTML = http.GetString(newURL)
        Dim tables As Object

        Set tables = html.querySelectorAll("table")

        For j = 0 To tables.Length - 1
            clipboard.SetText tables.item(j).outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard
            ws.Cells(LastRow(ws) + 2, 1).PasteSpecial
        Next
    Next
End Sub

'https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Public Function LastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function GetLinksAndIds(ByVal URL) As Variant
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, i As Long
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("btnSubmit1").Click

         While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim caseLinks As Object, id As String, newURL As String
        Set caseLinks = .document.querySelectorAll("[href*='CaseID=']")

        Dim linksAndIds()
        ReDim linksAndIds(1 To caseLinks.Length, 1 To 2)
        For i = 0 To caseLinks.Length - 1
           linksAndIds(i + 1, 1) = caseLinks.item(i)
           linksAndIds(i + 1, 2) = Replace$(caseLinks.item(i), "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=", vbNullString)
        Next

        .Quit
    End With
    GetLinksAndIds = linksAndIds
End Function
```

---

All Internet Explorer option:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTables()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim initialLinksURL As String, i As Long, j As Long, newURL As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    initialLinksURL = "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/LegacyCDS/Search"

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, caseLinks As Object
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 initialLinksURL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("btnSubmit1").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set caseLinks = .document.querySelectorAll("[href*='CaseID=']")

        Dim linksAndIds()
        ReDim linksAndIds(1 To caseLinks.Length, 1 To 2)
        For i = 0 To caseLinks.Length - 1
            linksAndIds(i + 1, 1) = caseLinks.item(i)
            linksAndIds(i + 1, 2) = Replace$(caseLinks.item(i), "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=", vbNullString)
        Next

        For i = LBound(linksAndIds, 2) To 2      ' UBound(linksAndIds, 2)

            newURL = "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewPage&xsl=Case.xsl&tab=Crash&form=CaseForm&baseNode=&vehnum=-1&occnum=-1&pos=-1&pos2=-1&websrc=true&title=Crash%20Overview%20-%20Summary&caseid=" & linksAndIds(i, 2) & "&year=&fullimage=false"
            .Navigate2 newURL

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Dim tables As Object

            Set tables = .document.querySelectorAll("table")

            For j = 0 To tables.Length - 1
                clipboard.SetText tables.item(j).outerHTML
                clipboard.PutInClipboard
                ws.Cells(LastRow(ws) + 2, 1).PasteSpecial
            Next
        Next

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

'https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Public Function LastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be a more elegant way to solve my problem. Unfortunately, I cannot get past the .send within the CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") without an error.

Comment: What is the error message please? I have just tested for first two links and it works. Just annoying as tables are listed one under the other all the way through. That is where using xpath may be more useful to determine a more consistent layout going across the page but would require more thought than I can give at present.

Comment: The error code is a runtime error  '-2146697211 (800c0005)'.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726661/error-from-vb-excel-macro-code-msxml3-dll-2146697211-the-system-cannot-locate

It did not help to change "Get" to "Post". Btw. I am using XML, v6.0.

Thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: There may even be someone who is going with transforming xml that could write something nice you could call as a sub in the loop to help with extraction in a format lending itself to writing across the page.

Comment: Yes, it stops as soon as I get there the first time. I had the same problem with the  trial code on the website of your first link https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/ .

Comment: Then I get runtime error '-2147012889 (80072ee7)'
After the ".Open "GET", URL, False" my http object still has "unknown error" for most of its variables including responseText.

Comment: Did you say you also tried the coding is love example and same problem? I am wondering if there is some kind of security setting applied.

Comment: Yes, this one:


Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String

myurl = "http://requestb.in/15oxrjh1" //replace with your URL
3
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False

xmlhttp.Send

MsgBox(xmlhttp.responseText)


Security probably is applied since I am using this at work which also prevents me from doing it with any other programming language or tool.

Comment: Will you have a chance to test on another machine? Otherwise, as I said, you can easily re-work the above to use Internet Explorer only if that can navigate to the pages. I may quickly draft something for you now.

Comment: I will check it as soon as I get home from work and if it works it probably has something to do with the security settings here. What exactly happens when you call the .send function as it might be relevant for security settings?

Please do not invest too much time in my problems. You already did me a great favor and I am always impressed by how people like you actually seem to understand programming and do not just use it the way I do like a patch work.

Comment: .Send does as it says... it attempts to rely your GET request to the target API service.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have given me enough advice that I can figure out a way to achieve my goal. It might not be the nicest way, but it is a good start to get a result. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. Let me know if any further queries.