# Run-time error ‘-2146697211(800c0005)’ in parsing site programm

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, internet-explorer, windows-10

I have a program that parse the site . Works perfect (on windows 7) . But after buying a new computer (and installing windows 10) problems started . An error pops up :  Run-time error ‘-2146697211(800c0005)’ in a row oHttp.Send . And exactly after the variable “S” changes . After that , the internet speed drops to 0 and restored only after some time . Bluetooth is disabled . I understand that the question is slightly off topic , but can anyone come across such a problem ?

```
Sub Softочки()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Call mainмассивы
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub mainмассивы()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim iLoop As Long
    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim book2 As Workbook
    Dim Ssilka As String
    Dim A As Long
    Dim S As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim W

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    W = Array("прошлый", "допрошлый", "додопрошлый")

    For S = 1 To 2
        Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Поиск решения\Усов 7\вспомогательные программы\3 сезона\" + W(S) + "\таблица.xlsm")
        For t = 1 To 98
            Set book2 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Поиск решения\Усов 7\вспомогательные программы\3 сезона\" + W(S) + "\" & t & ".xlsm")

            With book1.Worksheets("таблица").Range("AF34:AF53")
                iLoop = 0
                For Each r In .Rows

                    If r.Value = 5 Then
                        iLoop = iLoop + 1
                        Ssilka = r.Offset(0, -30).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
                        book2.Worksheets("Лист" & iLoop).Activate
                        extractTable Ssilka, book2, iLoop
                    End If
                Next r
            End With

            book2.Save
            book2.Close
        Next t
        book1.Close
    Next S

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Function extractTable(Ssilka As String, book2 As Workbook, iLoop As Long)
    Dim oDom As Object, oTable As Object, oRow As Object
    Dim iRows As Integer, iCols As Integer
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
    Dim data()
    Dim vata()
    Dim tata()
    Dim oHttp As Object
    Dim oRegEx As Object
    Dim sResponse As String
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim odRange As Range

    ' get page
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oHttp.Open "GET", Ssilka, False
    oHttp.Send

    ' cleanup response
    sResponse = StrConv(oHttp.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    Set oHttp = Nothing

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With oRegEx
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "<(script|SCRIPT)[\w\W]+?</\1>"
        sResponse = .Replace(sResponse, "")
    End With
    Set oRegEx = Nothing

    ' create Document from response
    Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
    oDom.Write sResponse
    DoEvents

    ' table with results, indexes starts with zero
    Set oTable = oDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(3)

    DoEvents

    iRows = oTable.Rows.Length
    iCols = oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length

    ' first row and first column contain no intresting data
    ReDim data(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)
    ReDim vata(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)
    ReDim tata(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)
    ' fill in data array
    For x = 1 To iRows - 1
        Set oRow = oTable.Rows(x)

        For y = 1 To iCols - 1
            If oRow.Cells(y).Children.Length > 0 Then
                data(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).getelementsbytagname("a")(0).getattribute("href")
                data(x, y) = Replace(data(x, y), "about:", "http://allscores.ru/soccer/")
                vata(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).innerText

            End If

        Next y
    Next x

    Set oRow = Nothing
    Set oTable = Nothing
    Set oDom = Nothing


    Set oRange = book2.ActiveSheet.Cells(110, 2).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
    oRange.NumberFormat = "@"
    oRange.Value = data

    Set odRange = book2.ActiveSheet.Cells(34, 2).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
    odRange.NumberFormat = "@"
    odRange.Value = vata

    Set odRange = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Does the answer by user [psiphi75](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804847/psiphi75) in [Error from VB excel macro code - msxml3.dll -2146697211 The system cannot locate the resource specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141222/1115360) help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton , thank you .